# Mysql - Need solution for removing nested query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a mysql query as below:

```
SELECT questionid, question_number, question, actual_score, total_score, 
ROUND(((actual_score / total_score) * 100), 2) AS satisfaction FROM 
(
SELECT seq.`questionid`, seq.`question_number`, seql.`question`, 
SUM(sea.`score`) AS actual_score,
SUM(seq.`max_score`) AS total_score
 -- round(((sea.`score` / seq.`max_score`) * 100), 2) as satisfaction
FROM `survey_event_questions` seq
INNER JOIN `survey_event_question_langs` seql ON seq.`questionid` = seql.`questionid` AND seql.`langid` = '1'
INNER JOIN `survey_event_answers` sea ON seq.`questionid` = sea.`questionid`
INNER JOIN `survey_events` se ON sea.`eventid` = se.`eventid`
WHERE seq.`event_typeid` = '1' AND seq.`max_score` > 0 AND se.`survey_date` BETWEEN 
'2014-01-02 13:00:00' AND '2014-05-02 14:59:59' AND se.`event_status` = 'Closed'
GROUP BY seq.`questionid`
) AS tbl;
```

This query sum up the column values for sea.score and seq.max_score and calculate the satisfaction value correctly.

I want to do it without using nested query. The single query i am using is given below.

```
SELECT seq.`questionid`, seq.`question_number`, seql.`question`, 
SUM(sea.`score`) AS actual_score,
SUM(seq.`max_score`) AS total_score,
round(((sea.`score` / seq.`max_score`) * 100), 2) as satisfaction
FROM `survey_event_questions` seq
INNER JOIN `survey_event_question_langs` seql ON seq.`questionid` = seql.`questionid` AND seql.`langid` = '1'
INNER JOIN `survey_event_answers` sea ON seq.`questionid` = sea.`questionid`
INNER JOIN `survey_events` se ON sea.`eventid` = se.`eventid`
WHERE seq.`event_typeid` = '1' AND seq.`max_score` > 0 AND se.`survey_date` BETWEEN 
'2014-01-02 13:00:00' AND '2014-05-02 14:59:59' AND se.`event_status` = 'Closed'
GROUP BY seq.`questionid`
```

When I run this query it given me wrong calculation for satisfaction column but works fine when I use nested query.

Comment: If the nested query is producing the right answer, why do you want to change it?

Comment: because single query perform better than nested query.

Comment: So this is actually a question about improving performance?

Comment: Not really....i only want the solution for solving this using single query....Can u please tell me why you have downrated my this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below query

```
SELECT seq.`questionid`, seq.`question_number`, seql.`question`, 
SUM(sea.`score`) AS actual_score,
SUM(seq.`max_score`) AS total_score,
round(((SUM(sea.`score`) / SUM(seq.`max_score`)) * 100), 2) as satisfaction
FROM `survey_event_questions` seq
INNER JOIN `survey_event_question_langs` seql 
ON seq.`questionid` = seql.`questionid` 
AND seql.`langid` = '1'
INNER JOIN `survey_event_answers` sea ON seq.`questionid` = sea.`questionid`
INNER JOIN `survey_events` se ON sea.`eventid` = se.`eventid`
WHERE seq.`event_typeid` = '1' AND seq.`max_score` > 0 
AND se.`survey_date` BETWEEN 
'2014-01-02 13:00:00' AND '2014-05-02 14:59:59' AND se.`event_status` = 'Closed'
GROUP BY seq.`questionid`
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but i don't want to use the aggregate function "SUM" again for the two columns. Can we do something using alias or mysql variables???

Comment: @tanrich Why don't you want to use the aggregate function "SUM" again

Comment: Because there is no use of calculating the sum again for the same column....using this function again will force the query to take more time to execute. I know there is not a big performance issue but still i am looking for a solution for using sum function only once.